# Does Google analyze uploaded .apk for warnings or errors? Does it affect play market ranking?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have been using android studio Analyze->Inspect Code…  - results often impressive. I started wondering - does Google analyze uploaded .apk file for Lint warnings or some kind of errors? Or even check if you followed their guidelines in app development.
Does it have influence on play market search result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mention of any APK analysis in [Android publishing documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html). I believe your app *can* get [flagged](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4454558), if you go against [guidelines](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113474). This can result in suspension of your app among other consequences, but none of this affects your Google Play search indexing (aside from the fact you may not be on it if your app is suspended).

It seems a [review process](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-gen-08) exists for Chrome apps, so perhaps there may be one for Android as well.